# How to Override CSS class?

Tags: html, css

I am working a component based framework where in component below css class applied which is changing background color of component

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(119, 44, 44) 0%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 100%);
```

But i have want this background color of component

```
background-color: #f2dede;
```

What changes i have to do in above CSS class so it will apply `background-color: #f2dede;`

Comment: You can't just replace one with the other?

Comment: If i am replacing background-image class from background-color its not working

Comment: background-image is not a class but a property. You cannot replace background -image property with background-color property. They are separate entities.

Comment: simply use background:#f2dede !important;.. I dont recommend using !important as a good approach, but try..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

all you have to do to overwrite a css property is to write it again but after the declaration. The browser reads you style file from the top to the bottom and applies only the last declaration of the same element.

```css
.catsandstars {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image:  url("https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/images/startransparent.gif");
}
```

```html
<div class="catsandstars"></div>
```

and here is how you properly overwrite it

```css
.catsandstars {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image:  url("https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/images/startransparent.gif");
  background-color: transparent;
}
.catsandstars {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
```

```html
<div class="catsandstars"></div>
```

[**The !important exception**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

> When an !important rule is used on a style declaration, this
> declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever
> it is in the declaration list. Although, !important has nothing to do
> with specificity.  Using !important is bad practice because it makes
> debugging hard since you break the natural cascading in your
> stylesheets.

**Some rules of thumb**

> **Never** use !important on site-wide css.
>
> **Only** use !important on page-specific css that overrides site-wide or foreign css (from ExtJs or YUI for example).
>
> **Never** use !important when you're writing a  plugin/mashup.
>
> **Always** look for a way to use specificity before even
>
> considering !important

Answer (score 3):

Use this in css:-

```
.yourClass {
  background-image: none !important;
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted but you should avoid `!important` if you can, it's a crutch. It's better to understand CSS specificity https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.className{
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Try to have this code at the end of your CSS file so that your class gets overrided.

> Note : `.className` refers to the class identity for which the `background-image` has been given.

Answer (score -1):

```
.yourClass {
  background: #f2dede !important;
}
```